# Exe running from command line but not from php

Tags: php, c++, opencv, exe

I have a C++ executable which takes an image path as an input and does some image processing in the input image using opencv. When I try to run the executable from the command line it gives the output. But when I try to run it from php using the below code it crashes and gives me some error as shown below.

```
<?php
$date1 = new DateTime("now");

$name="/var/www/html/FailedBag2.jpg";
     $addr="/var/www/html/BagsFeature '$name'";
     exec($addr,$data);
     var_dump($data);
$date2 = new DateTime("now");
$interval = date_diff($date1, $date2);
echo "Time Taken to Generate Feature in seconds : ".$interval ->format('%s');
?>
```

Error that I get is:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (m.dims >= 2) in Mat, file /var/www/html/opencvpencv-2.4.5/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 269
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /var/www/html/opencv/opencv-2.4.5/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:269: ror: (-215) m.dims >= 2 in function Mat

Aborted (core dumped)
array(0) {
}
```

From the command line I run the exe by:

```
cd /var/www/html

./BagsFeature /var/www/html/FailedBag2.jpg
```

If the code had some problem it would have crashed in the command line also but it runs smoothly in the command line but crashes only if we call it from php.Is there any difference on calling the executable from php using exec and calling from the commandline itself? How can I solve this issue?

Another confusion is if I call the same executable with the same crashed image and same php code from another machine it runs. Is it anything to do with the php settings? And this problem is only in few images most of the images run from php.

Comment: What is `$data`, and how are you running this on the command-line?

Comment: $data is the variable where the string output from the c++ exec is stored..i have edited above the command that I use in the commandline to run the exe

Comment: Are you SURE you are running the same program - try adding something that prints a message and exits early. (May want to print the arguments too, just in case there's something fishy going on there)

Comment: your program *is* running, but it thinks, your image is invalid.

Comment: try `$addr="/var/www/html/BagsFeature $name";` instead